# How Oracle internally deduces the differece between dates

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```sql
select (current_date - TO_DATE('20210817124015','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) from dual;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 0.1229282407407407407407407407407407407407
> ```

I want to know how oracle internally achieves this value.

ps: the `current_date` and the hardcoded date are same, only time is the difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "internally"? Do you just want to know what the result ***means***? That's not what "internally" means. Or do you really want to know how Oracle does this "internally" - meaning, how it has implemented the calculation in code? That is probably a trade secret - Oracle tells us what functions do, but it's not open source.

Answer (score 3):

`CURRENT_DATE` returns the current date and time in the user's session time zone.

`TO_DATE('20210817124015','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')` returns the date `2021-08-17T12:40:15`.

*Note: A `DATE` data type always has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components. However, the user interface you are using may chose not to show all the components.*

Subtracting one date from another returns the number of days between the two values.

0.1229282407407407407407407407407407407407 days is:

- 2.950277778 hours; or
- 177.016666667 minutes; or
- 10621 seconds; or
- 2 hours 57 minutes and 1 second.

So your current date was `2021-08-17T12:40:15 + 10621 seconds` or `2021-08-17T15:37:16`.

For example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Samarkand';

SELECT CURRENT_DATE,
       TO_DATE('20210817124015','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') As other_date,
       CURRENT_DATE - TO_DATE('20210817124015','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as difference,
       (CURRENT_DATE - TO_DATE('20210817124015','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) DAY TO SECOND
         as interval_difference
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CURRENT_DATE | OTHER_DATE | DIFFERENCE | INTERVAL_DIFFERENCE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-08-17T15:40:01 | 2021-08-17T12:40:15 | .124837962962962962962962962962962962963 | +00 02:59:46.000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a7ebf823f934898de4a332f02f3a9adf)*

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting two dates returns a difference in days.

0.1229282407407407407407407407407407407407 days is

- 2.9502777777768 hours
- 177.016666666608 minutes
- 10621 seconds

Or, put another way, `current_date` is returning a date value that is 2 hours 57 minutes and 1 second after the hard-coded date.  Since the hard-coded date has a time of 12:40:51, that means that `current_date` has a time of 15:37:52.